# Error 500 after modifying htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

After adding this to .htaccess

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
```

I had the 500 error in the website . 
I added those lines in the end of the file and just before there is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Do you see any problem ?

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to see what the error is?

Comment: Is mod_expires enabled on the server?

Comment: /usr/sbin/apache2 -l does not show mod_expires . I think this is the problem . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a problem either, had ExpiresByType in my .htaccess files for years. As of two days ago, those lines and a few others had to be removed my .htacess files to get my websites back online.  The other offending lines:

`Header unset ETag`

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js|swf)$">

Header set Cache-Control "public"

</FilesMatch></code>
```